# Creating an Epub from scratch

Tags: html, xml, epub3, calibre

I am making a childen's illustrated books with links on the pages...like a Choose Your Own Adventure book for kids.

I have created a "Book Title" Folder. Inside of that folder is an OEBPS Folder, with the images, html text files, audio, and 'content.opf" file.

There's also the META-INF folder with the container.xml file inside.

```
folder/
    META-INF/
        container.xml
    mimetype
    OEBPS/
        content.opf
        images
        text
        music
        css
```

But I can't figure out how to turn it all into an epub. I'm sure the html is right. But Calibre just won't take everything like it should and create it.

Any other ideas or suggestions?

I tried 'adding book' in calibre, and it was supposed to read everything in the Book's folder and compile it into an ebook...but it did not. It seemed to only find image47 and Page 47.html

The Content.opf fille includes this code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package version="3.0" unique-identifier="bookid" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:title>The Rainbow Stone</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>My Name</dc:creator>
    <dc:publisher>Constellation Publishing</dc:publisher>
    <dc:language>en-US</dc:language>
    <dc:description>A magical story about a rainbow stone</dc:description>
    <dc:identifier id="bookid">urn:uuid:550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000</dc:identifier>
  </metadata>
  <manifest>
    <item id="css1" href="Making Smaller Images.css" media-type="text/css"/>
    <item id="css2" href="Size for Images.css" media-type="text/css"/>
    <item id="audio1" href="Rainbow Stone Music.mp3" media-type="audio/mpeg"/>
    <item id="cover" href="Page 1.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="page2" href="Page 2.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <!-- add more pages here -->(these went up to page 66)
    <item id="image1" href="image1.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
    <item id="image2" href="image2.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg"/>
    <!-- add more images here -->(these went up to image 66)
  </manifest>
  <spine>
    <itemref idref="cover"/>
    <itemref idref="page1"/>
    <itemref idref="page2"/>
    <!-- add more pages here -->(these went up to page 66)
  </spine>
</package>
```

Inside the Meta-INF folder is the container.xml file.

This code is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">
  <rootfiles>
    <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
  </rootfiles>
</container>
```

Comment: `filenames` must not contain space characters and `ncx` is highly recommended...

Answer (score 0):

To create an `epub` file that can be imported into Calibre, the files in your `folder` directory need to be bundled in a zip file.

Using the `zip` command:

```bash
zip -r name_of_my_book.epub folder
```

where:

- `-r`: *travel the directory structure recursively*
- `name_of_my_book.epub`: *name of the epub*
- `folder`: *the directory containing the files to be turned into an epub*